# Looping in Array containing word-embedding

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, word-embedding

I wanted to check the cosine similarity of 1 element of the first array to all other elements of the 2nd array then the 2nd element of the first element to all elements of the 2nd array and so on. I also want to store all matching an array.

```
df1
title
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

df2
claim
fact checked claims one
fact checked claims tweet

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
title=df1['title'].tolist()
claim=df2['claim'].tolist()
title=model.encode(title)
claim=model.encode(claim)
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
for i in title:
   for j in claim:
      cosine_similarity(title[i].reshape(1,-1),claim[j].reshape(1,-1))
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-7d0694ac4823> in <module>()
  1 for i in title:
  2   for j in claim:
  ----> 3     cosine_similarity(title[i].reshape(1,-1),claim[j].reshape(1,-1))
  4 

 IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 oops, I have added the dataset,

Comment: Please post the entire error message beginning with Traceback

Comment: @itprorh66 updated the error, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The code is not indexing using the integer/boolean type variables.

In fact, the for loops in your code is *for-each* not *for-range*, and therefore variables i and j are equal to entire line (string) instead of their indices with respect to the whole file.

Therefore, you can either change to for-range loop:

```
for i in range(len(title)):
    for j in range(len(claim)):
        cosine_similarity(title[i].reshape(1,-1),claim[j].reshape(1,-1))
```

or reshape and compare i and j directly:

```
for i in title:
    for j in claim:
        cosine_similarity(i.reshape(1,-1),j.reshape(1,-1))
```